# Show own Cordova/PhoneGap App where user open any share dialog

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

Is there any setting or any plugin in Cordova from where my app  list down in share dialog, like facebook, twitter or flicker shown up to user when he open a share dialog or want to share something.

See picture for reference, I want to show my app in this dialog and when user clicks to share, my app should accept that shared content.

[image]

Comment: Do you have any updates for the question?

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your config.xml

```
  <gap:config-file platform="android" parent="/manifest/application" mode="add" >
<activity android:name="urlscheme1" android:label="@string/app_name">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<data android:mimeType="text/*" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
</gap:config-file>
```

Comment: but that only works on android. is there any way to achieve the same thing on iOS?

Comment: Haven't tried for iOS, but maybe you could try this http://www.tricedesigns.com/2012/08/15/open-with-in-ios-phonegap-apps/